# How to sort a list of tuples by different order for each element?

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have the following:

```
l = [([2, 0], 'GRD'), ([2, 1, 0], 'GLFN'), ([2, 1, 0], 'GRN'), ([3, 1, 0], 'GRFN'), ([4, 0], 'GRFFTH'), ([4, 0], 'GRFFY')]
r = sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]), reverse=True)
```

How would I sort this so that `r` is:

```
[([4, 0], 'GRFFTH'), ([4, 0], 'GRFFY'), ([3, 1, 0], 'GRFN'), ([2, 1, 0], 'GLFN'), ([2, 1, 0], 'GRN'), ([2, 0], 'GRD')]
```

That is:

- Sort according to the number lists in reverse order.
- Then sort according to the strings in ascending order when the lists are equal.

My sort is sorting the strings in reverse alphabetical order, but I want it in alphabetical order. Only the number lists should be sorted in reverse.

My code gives the following output:

```
[([4, 0], 'GRFFY'), ([4, 0], 'GRFFTH'), ([3, 1, 0], 'GRFN'), ([2, 1, 0], 'GRN'), ([2, 1, 0], 'GLFN'), ([2, 0], 'GRD')]
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the sorting algorithm used in Python is [stable](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts), this kind of complex sort can be done in few passes:

```
r = sorted(l, key=itemgetter(1))
r = sorted(r, key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
```

As the official tutorial above says:

> The Timsort algorithm used in Python does multiple sorts efficiently because it can take advantage of any ordering already present in a dataset.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way of sorting numerical objects in reverse order without using the `reverse` argument is by negating them. So you *could* do:

```py
r = sorted(l, key=lambda tup: ([-num for num in tup[0]], tup[1]))
```

Which will give the desired:

```
[([4, 0], 'GRFFTH'), ([4, 0], 'GRFFY'), ([3, 1, 0], 'GRFN'), ([2, 1, 0], 'GLFN'), ([2, 1, 0], 'GRN'), ([2, 0], 'GRD')]
```

Worth noting that this will create a new list for each list of numbers in `l` to do the compare. Might get inefficient for very big lists.

Answer (score 2):

You can sort based on the strings first, then sort the result of that in reverse using the list as key, as follows:

```
l1 = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[1])
l = sorted(l1, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
```

This gives the following output as desired:

```
[([4, 0], 'GRFFTH'), ([4, 0], 'GRFFY'), ([3, 1, 0], 'GRFN'), ([2, 1, 0], 'GLFN'), ([2, 1, 0], 'GRN'), ([2, 0], 'GRD')]
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to do it in just one statement, you could do:

```
l = sorted(sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[1]), key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
```